# Object not set to reference in build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having some discrepancy between playing my unity project inside the editor, and playing the build it makes.

Inside the editor, when I play my game I have code that spawns enemies when my player hits a target spot, which works. The enemies spawn and do what they need to do. However, when I build the project and run it, my player hits the same spot, but nothing appears.

I ran the project in the development mode and it claims I have not set the reference which I thought I had. I mean, if it didn't work, why is it working in the editor?

To try and combat this, I re-imported the assets I'm using. I remade the enemy spawn points. But I still get the same issue.

Has anyone ever came across this before? 
If so, how can I fix this issue when it works inside the editor, but not in the build?

Here is my spawning function:

```
public GameObject SpawnEnemies()
{
    Vector3 _position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

    // instantiate particel system
  //  Instantiate(_particle, _position, Quaternion.identity);
    audio.PlayOneShot(_appearSound);

    _clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(_enemy, _position, transform.rotation);
    _ai = _clone.GetComponent<HV_BaseAI>();
    _ai._waypoints = _wayPoints;

    return _clone;
}
```

This is controlled by my section class which has the following function:

```
   public List<GameObject> SpawnGroundEnemies()
{
    List<GameObject> groundObjectList = new List<GameObject>();

    for (int i = 0; i < _spawnPoints.Count; i++)
    {
        groundObjectList.Add(_spawnPoints[i].SpawnEnemies());
    }
    return groundObjectList;
}
```

Which, in turn is controlled by my section controller:

```
       GameObject g, f;
    g = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SectionController");
    f = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("SectionController");

    HV_SectionController tempSectionControllerGroundEnemies, tempSectionControllerFlyingEnemies;
    tempSectionControllerGroundEnemies = g.GetComponent<HV_SectionController>();
    tempSectionControllerFlyingEnemies = f.GetComponent<HV_SectionController>();

    _groundEnemiesRemaining = tempSectionControllerGroundEnemies._numberOfGroundEnemies.Count;
    _flyingEnemiesRemaining = tempSectionControllerFlyingEnemies._numberOfFlyingEnemies.Count;
    _enemiesRemaining = _groundEnemiesRemaining + _flyingEnemiesRemaining;

    if (!_moving)
    {
        if (_enemiesRemaining == 0)
        {
            MoveToNextSection();

        }

    }

    if (_moving)
    {
        if (Vector3.SqrMagnitude(_camera.transform.position - _camNavMesh.destination) < 5.0f)
        {
            _moving = false;


            // spawn the next set of enemies
            // need this for each section of the game
            // without this, no enemies will spawn
            if (CurrentSection == 1)
            {
                _numberOfGroundEnemies = _sections[0].SpawnGroundEnemies();
                _enemiesRemaining = _numberOfGroundEnemies.Count;
            }

            if (CurrentSection == 2)
            {
                _numberOfFlyingEnemies = _sections[1].SpawnFlyingEnemies();
                _enemiesRemaining = _numberOfFlyingEnemies.Count;
            }

            if (CurrentSection == 3)
            {
                _numberOfGroundEnemies = _sections[2].SpawnGroundEnemies();
                _enemiesRemaining = _numberOfGroundEnemies.Count;
            }
        }
    }
}

private void MoveToNextSection()
{
    if (_currentSection == _sections.Count)
    {
        _currentSection = 0;
    }
    _camNavMesh.SetDestination(_sections[_currentSection]._cameraTransform.position);
    _lookAtPoint.SetTimer(_sections[_currentSection]._cameraLookAtTarget.position);
    _moving = true;

    _currentSection += 1;
}
```

Can anyone see anything i'm doing wrong?

Update

Since this post, I've tried reimporting all of my assets again. I've even created a fresh project and done a fresh build that way, but I still have the same issue. Also, to help, I've take two screen grabs to show what I mean.

First off, the game running in the unity editor:
[image]

As you can see, there is 4 skeletons on the bridge. These guys appear when I hit play in the unity editor.

Now, when I build the project, this is same sections:
[image]

As you can see, no enemies, but when its a development build, it says I've no reference set. In the output log unity genereates, it gives me this message:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object   at HV_SpawnGroundEnemy.SpawnEnemies () [0x00052] in
>   C:\Users\sean.obrien\Desktop\Medieval Darkride
>   Level\Assets_scripts\Enemy Scripts\HV_SpawnGroundEnemy.cs:37
>
> at HV_Section.SpawnGroundEnemies () [0x0000d] in
>   C:\Users\sean.obrien\Desktop\Medieval Darkride
>   Level\Assets_scripts\Helper Scripts\HV_Section.cs:26
>
> at HV_SectionController.Update () [0x000c2] in
>   C:\Users\sean.obrien\Desktop\Medieval Darkride
>   Level\Assets_scripts\Helper Scripts\HV_SectionController.cs:72

Again, this only appears in the built version of the game. When I run this inside Unity, everything works fine. I honestly have no idea why this issue arises when it works fine in the editor but not in the build.

Comment: Can you provide any relevant code?

Comment: Are the enemies being loaded via Resource.Load? What platform are you building and testing on?

Comment: Tried cleaning your solution and rebuilding? You can attach your debugger to the (externally) running process and then look at what's going on from there.

Comment: Built development build of my project. It says that no object reference has been set when it tries to spawn enemies. But if that were true, it wouldn't work in the editor. That#s the reason I'm so stumped.

Comment: Are you instantiating the enemies via a prefab instantiation call?

If so, they might be spawning without variables that you would normally set through the Inspector. You'll have to programmatically assign the values for these variables.

Comment: Maybe we could take the guess work out by noting (in OPs example code) which lines the debug output is referring to?  This could be something as simple as `_appearSound` not being assigned, blocking enemy spawn.

Comment: Yeah, I took out the _appearSound line and it works.I feel an idiot....

Answer (score 0):

There's most probably two cases here. Either you've not saved your scene yet, or you're not including the correct scene while making the build.

If it's the first case, just save the scene. If it's second, then you need to choose proper scene in the build settings and then rebuild.

**Explanation:**
You might have saved the scene as some other file, but the build setting does not update the scene file dynamically. It'll still point to the old scene. So you just need to remove the old scene and add the current scene you're using.